# How can you call a templated controller action for a unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here are two actions on a controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] UserDto user)
{
    // create a new user
}

[HttpPost("usergroup")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] UserGroupDto usergroup)
{
    // create a new user group
}
```

When writing unit tests for these, I can call the first one easily:

```
var controller = new UserController();
var userDto = new UserDto{ UuId = Guid.NewGuid() };
var result = await controller.Post(userDto);
```

But I can't see a path on the controller to call the post action with the path template. What's the syntax to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is a simple overloaded method, it has nothing to do with the http verb. It might be confusing because your method is named `Post`. That's just the method name, you are not actually doing a `POST` action.

To call the other method, just use normal calls:

```
var controller = new UserController();
var userGroupDto = new UserGroupDto { UuId = Guid.NewGuid() };
var result = await controller.Post(userGroupDto);
```

It might be even easier to see why and how this works, if you rename your methods to `CreateUser` and `CreateGroup`.